# Python Game always crash or stuck | pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a nice game with the `pygame` module, and basically I want to do two things:

1. Run the game in an endless loop and see if the user wants to close the game, and if he wants to close the game, pop him a MessageBox.
2. In the second function, I want to add all the features of the game and draw on the screen.

My problem is that when I try to run them both with Thread, the game gets stuck and unresponsive.

Is this a problem with my computer, meaning it's too weak to run the game?
Or is it a problem with my code that keeps the game from running properly?

**Code:**

```
import pygame
import ctypes
from threading import Thread

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init = pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))
        self.allProcess()

    def runGame(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, 'Thank you for Playing!', 'Thank You', 0)
                    self.running = False

    def items(self):
        self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 75)

    def allProcess(self):
        Thread(target=self.runGame).start()
        Thread(target=self.items).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ins = Game()
```

Comment: You should add `pygame.display.flip` to show the circle

Comment: Also, why exactly do you want to use threads here? There may be an easier solution

Comment: @Nathan Hey! Because I want to run my game in endless loop, without this my game will close automatically after some seconds.

Comment: You definitely do not need threads to make and endless loop. Just use `while True:`

Comment: @daReagion maybe it would be good to have a look at how other people solve this problem, for instance: https://gitlab.com/nathan_vanthof/space_invaders/blob/master/core/game_mechanics.py

Comment: @Nathan Cool, Nathan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygame is built on SDL2 which has some rules regarding in which threads certain functions can be called. For example, for functions in the event module, (*["you can only call this function in the thread that set the video mode."](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent)*).

You should almost always avoid using threads unless they are absolutely necessary! They make your program non-deterministic, harder to debug, harder to test, harder to maintain and often slower (unless you use them effectively). In your program, there are no reasons to use threads. In your case, they are unnecessary. You should do this instead:

```
import pygame
import ctypes

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init = pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))
        self.runGame()

    def runGame(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, 'Thank you for Playing!', 'Thank You', 0)
                    self.running = False

            self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 75)

            pygame.display.flip()  # Don't forget to call this to update the screen!



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ins = Game()
```

Less code, deterministic, and most likely faster and using less memory.