# Error while using multiprocessing in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i'm making a text-based RPG and am trying to use multiproccessing to run both the pygame check function and the game function at the same time. This is my first time using multiprocessing so i'm not entirely sure what is going on.

Here is the (important) code:

```
from csv import reader
import pygame
from sys import exit
import multiprocessing
```

```
def check():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

def startgame():
    play(input("Present Command\n"))

play_game_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=startgame)
play_game_process.start()

check_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=check)
check_process.start()
```

When i run the code, i am hit with a very large error message:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.8)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.8)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.8)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Dougl\Documents\Coding\Python\games\Command\command.py", line 193, in <module>
    play_game_process.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Dougl\Documents\Coding\Python\games\Command\command.py", line 193, in <module>
    play_game_process.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

I am not sure what is going on here, please help if you can!

Comment: [You can't access the event loop from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60018431/6486738). I'd suggest avoiding threading completely as pygame creates the necessary threads for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the end of the error message, and the very clear instructions there? When using multiprocessing, your main code needs to be wrapped in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` idiom (this is also documented in the `multiprocessing` docs).

I.e. something like

```
import multiprocessing
from sys import exit

import pygame


def check():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()


def startgame():
    play(input("Present Command\n"))


def main():
    play_game_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=startgame)
    play_game_process.start()

    check_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=check)
    check_process.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note, however, that that probably won't do what you want, since the `check` and `startgame` functions will be run in *entirely different processes* which don't know about each other at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, it really helped me out. The only problem now is when i try to run the updated code, the pygame windows launches three times, and then crashes instantly. It doesn't give me any error message so i know the syntax is valid, but i am not sure where i went wrong. Here is the code for the window:

Comment: ```
background_colour = (0,0,0)
width, height = 1920, 1080
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Command")
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()
```
and here is the code for the run loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
```

Comment: That initialization code should be in the `main` function, so you don't get three Pygames initializing (one in the parent and two in the children) – but again, you really don't want to use `multiprocessing` for this.

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest, how could I perform the same code but without multiprocessing?

Comment: @Crazyscientist09 You can't (within reason) have blocking code in event-driven (i.e. GUI) applications. `input` blocks execution so you shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: Ok thank you, but in that case, how might I get input from the user without slowing down my code?

Comment: You'll need to read the key events from the user in the Pygame event loop.

Comment: Oh ok thank you I will try this as soon as I can

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble, how would I implement this into the code I already have?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992814/pygame-is-there-any-easy-way-to-find-the-letter-number-of-any-alphanumeric-pres . . .